# Composer-cli does not seem to know runtime for an argument

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm doing the developers tutorial found here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.16/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

On the step where you have to runtime install I call this command:

```
composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName tutorial-network
```

But get the following error:

```
Unknown arguments: card, businessNetworkName, runtime, install
```

Ive looked through the composer-cli documentation and runtime is still in there. Is the documentation out-dated or what else might be going wrong here. I'm absolutly clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a tutorial for the version v0.16 - this is now quite dated and unless you are specifically using this version you should use the *latest* doc and the *latest* Composer version.

The latest doc is here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial

Check you version of Composer with `composer -v` hopefully you are using v0.19.6 or similar.

(Composer runtime install was a v0.16 command and no longer present in v0.19.* - the new commands are in the tutorial.)

Composer v0.19.* works with Fabric v1.1.0 - this is the latest version and hopefully this is the version you have.  You can check your Fabric version by using `docker images` and you should see image names ending **-1.1.0**  If not you will need to remove the existing containers and images and re-do the step to create the Development Fabric as described in the *latest* docs.